# generate array between two numbers without linQ c#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I wan't to generate an `int[]` with numbers between 500-1500 without LINQ or lambda expressions, and then see if it equal divided by 3 the numbers between and then sum it and calc the average in the sum.

How do I do it without LINQ or lambda expressions.

This is a C# console application

I tried this so far:

```
        int[] tal = new int[1500];

        for (int i = 500; i < tal.Length; i++)
        {
            tal[i] += i;
        }

        int summa = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 1500; i++)
        {
            if (tal[i] % 3 == 0)
            {
                summa += tal[i];
            }
            }
```

Comment: To generate the array, you just need a normal array creation expression and then a for loop...

Comment: _"see if it equal divided by 3 the numbers between and then sum it and calc the average in the sum"_ can you xplain that in other words?

Comment: _between 500-1500_  your array should be 1000 of length. and fill it like this`tal[i] += i + 500;`

Answer (score 4):

Creation:

```
  // inclusive
  int from = 500;
  // inclusive
  int to = 1000;

  int[] tal = new int[from - to + 1]; // both "from" and "to" are inclusive

  for (int i = 0; i < tal.Length; ++i)
    tal[i] = from + i;
```

Summation/Average:

```
  int summa = 0;
  int count = 0; 

  foreach (var v in tal)
    if (v % 3 == 0) {
      summa += v;
      count += 1;
    }

  Double average = ((Double)summa) / count;
```

Just for *reference*, Linq solutions:

```
  var summa = Enumerable
    .Range(from, to - from + 1) // both "from" and "to" are inclusive
    .Where(item => item % 3 == 0)
    .Sum();

  var average = Enumerable
    .Range(from, to - from + 1) // both "from" and "to" are inclusive
    .Where(item => item % 3 == 0)
    .Average();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here i solution:

```
const int from = 501, to = 1500;
const int n = (to - from)/3 + 1;
const int result = (from + to)*n/2;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

it definitely do not use LINQ, lambdas or even arrays (because they are not needed here) or variables (all const expressions will be evaluated in compile-time). You may want to reduce it, so result program will be:

```
Console.WriteLine((501 + 1500)*((1500 - 501)/3 + 1)/2);
```

or even

```
Console.WriteLine(334167);
```

if you need an average, then `n`'s are reduced and you can write:

```
const int from = 501, to = 1500;
const double result = (from + to)/2.0;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] tal = new int[1500];
```

This initializes an array of length 1500.

```
for (int i = 500; i < tal.Length; i++)
```

This inserts 1000 numbers into the array (from 500 to 1499).

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 1500; i++)
```

This iterates through 1501 numbers in the array.

Thus, your array should be an `int[1000]` and the condition in the second loop `i < 1000`. Or maybe `int[1001]` and the condition in your first for loop should be `i <= tal.Length`, if you want all numbers from 500 to 1500.

Comment: Actually the last line iterates over *1501* numbers in the array, which is also a problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks for noticing. Edit made.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `List<int>` which you can fill in the `for`-loop. Then you can use [`List<T>.ToArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx)(not LINQ) to create the final `int[]`:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
decimal sum = 0;
for (int i = 500; i <= 1500; i++)
{
    bool divisibleBy3 = i % 3 == 0;
    if (divisibleBy3)
    {
        numbers.Add(i);
        sum += i;
    }
}
decimal average = 0m;
if (numbers.Count > 0)
    average = sum / numbers.Count;
int[] result = numbers.ToArray();
```

If you can't use any .NET methods you can fill your `int[]` in a loop:

```
int[] result = new int[numbers.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
    result[i] = numbers[i];
```

Comment: I want to use an array not list

Comment: @AlexanderHalef: i'm using an array. Look at the introductory phrase and the last line of my code. You don't know beforehand how many items the collection will contain, then i would always prefer a list. The `list.ToArray` is a O(n) operation so it's quite efficient.

Comment: @AlexanderHalef: However, i have added a way to initialize the array without .NET methods.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to create `1500` length array. since you dont need first `500` elements. also use a counter to count number of sums done inside second loop, then take average.

```
int[] tal = new int[1000];

for (int i = 0; i < tal.Length; i++)
{
    tal[i] += i + 500; // 500 based number
}

int summa = 0;
int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < tal.Length; i++)
{
    if (tal[i] % 3 == 0)
    {
        summa += tal[i];
        k++; // count number of summed.
    }
}

double average = 0;

if(k != 0) // prevent division by zero
{
    average = (double)summa/k; // cast to double to hold precision.
}

Console.WriteLine(average);
```

Answer (score -1):

For the array generation you can use `int[] tal = Enumerable.Range(500, 1000).ToArray();` The logic can stay the same